# Good books for porting android/java to ios/objective c

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, porting

I spent the last year working on a project that involved mostly java for android but used c++ for some additional libraries through jni. What I would like to do is port the whole project into objective c for ios because I think it would make using the ios libraries that much easier not having to use any wrappers or additional code.

So does anybody know of any good books related to programing in objective c from the eyes of a java programmer. I already have quite a few objective c books and ios books but what Im lacking is the knowledge of how to cross over certain operations on objects and containers and things like that.

Any leads on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages

Comment: It's not exactly what you are looking. But you could begin with cocoa migration guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html

Comment: Hmmm.....that looks sort of promising thanks. Ill probably keep looking for some books that possibly deal with transferring from one to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Learn Objective-C for Java Developers' - (Apress).
http://books.google.co.nz/books/about/Learn_Objective_C_for_Java_Developers.html?id=2fQBGOU4UfQC&redir_esc=y