# If statement / String comparison

Tags: emacs, if-statement, comparison, elisp

I am new to `elisp` and am trying to write a simple program using an `if` statement.

The point is to read in a year of school and return either `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or `0` for the strings `"freshman"`, `"sophomore"`, `"junior"`, `"senior"` respectively (defaulting to `0` when no match is made.  My code is as follows:

```
(defun yearCode(name)
    (if ( = name "freshman") 1
      (if ( = name "sophomore") 2
        (if ( = name "junior") 3
          (if ( = name "senior") 4
            (0))))))


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; main function                        ;;;
;;; input: year                          ;;;
;;; output: code corresponding to year   ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun main (year)
 (interactive "sEnter your academic year: ")  ; read year
 (message "%d" (yearCode year)))              ; display its code

  ;;; Tests...
 (main "junior")
 (yearCode "junior")
```

I honestly know nothing about elisp so I am having trouble even having the first part compile. Can anyone help me construct an `if` statement correctly?

EDIT: I was testing in the wrong buffer -_- code worked using if statements.

Comment: That last edit totally changed the question...  The current `yearCode` definition will fail when you pass in a string that is not one of the four expected strings (after changing `=` to `string=`) because it has an expression where the first element isn't a function: `(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the way to write it using if statements. An if-statement has a condition part, which is either true or false. If it is true, it evaluates the FIRST part. It can only be one sentence really, unless you use `(progn )`. The rest of it will be the else part of the if statement.

```
(defun yearCode(name)
    (if (string= name "freshman")    ; true or false?
       1                            ; if true, returns 1 

  ; Note that you can't really write anything else here. 
  ; From here on, it is the first else part!

     (if (string= name "sophomore")  ; if false, else part  etc.
       2
      (if (string= name "junior") 
        3
       (if (string= name "senior") 
         4)))))
```

Though this answers your question specifically about `if`,  *I would certainly advise to use*  `cond`  *instead* , like the others suggested.

Below the application of `progn`, in the case of TRUE, to have more than 1 expression to be evaluated.

```
(defun yearCode(name)
    (if (string= name "freshman")    ; true or false?
       (progn 1                      ; if true, returns 1 
              (message "this is possible!"))          

     (if (string= name "sophomore")  ; if false, else part  etc.
       2
      (if (string= name "junior") 
        3
       (if (string= name "senior") 
         4)))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I figured it out. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: It should be emphasised that you really want to use `cond` instead, as the answers below demonstrate.

Comment: Added <em> emphasis </em>.

Answer (score 4):

When you have `if..elseif..elseif..else` in ruby, you use `cond` in emacs lisp:

```
(defun yearCode (name)
  (cond
   ((string= name "freshman") 1)
   ((string= name "sophomore") 2)
   ((string= name "junior") 3)
   ((string= name "senior") 4)))
```

That's not how I would write it, however.

```
(defun yearCode (name)
  (cdr (assoc name
              '(("freshman" . 1)
                ("sophomore" . 2)
                ("junior" . 3)
                ("senior" . 4)))))
```

There are many kind of equality, and `=` is strictly for numbers (or markers). `string=` is for strings and string *designators*, `eq` is for object identity, `equal` is a kind of deep equality of *elements* (that's why it works for strings, but it would just return false for string vs. non-string comparison, never detecting an error). This latter one, `equal`, is used by `assoc`.

Comment: doing it this way does in fact work. But is there a way to use if-statements? The whole point is to compare the different ways if-statements look using all different languages.

Comment: It would really be worth it to spend time getting to know `cond`. You can see it as an extension of if-statements, it really is just simplifying everything!

Answer (score 2):

The way to write your `yearCode` with minimal changes would be this:

```
(defun yearCode (name)
  (cond ((string= name "freshman") 1)
        ((string= name "sophomore") 2)
        ((string= name "junior") 3)
        ((string= name "senior") 4)
        (0)))
```

*Edited to add: the original version of the question was structured very differently, so the explanation below no longer applies...*

The difference between what you wrote and the above code is that in the above code, `yearCode` has one (`cond`) expression, and the return value of that function is the return value of the `cond` statement.

Your original code had 4 different expressions, only the value of the last expression is actually returned (the last `if`) statement - meaning the return value is either `4` or `nil`.

I recommend reading an introductory lisp book, my favorite is the [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), but you should probably check out the SO question asking for [best introductory books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages).

Comment: thank you for your input... I was working in the wrong buffer and was testing wrongly. Thank you so much for the information however I will use conditionals from now on :)