# Practicing C#, ASP.Net, Where to participate in projects to learn and be better

Tags: c#, asp.net, project

I am learning C#/.NET

I'm looking for websites with some projects, that I could review to develop my programming skills.

Comment: This is a very general question, but anyways: Apple ITunes U has some good free resources in the way of tutorials. Get involved in an open source project. Track the commits made by other users. Use Google!

Comment: I like pluralsight.com

Answer (score 1):

You should `google` a lot. But Here is some suggestions, what I prefer:

> 1. [dotnetpearl](http://www.dotnetpearl.com)       -->      `For very basic`
> 2. [codeproject](http://codeproject.com)       -->      `Specific projects on specific subject.`
> 3. [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)     -->      `For any kind of problem ;)`
> 4. [csharpcorner](http://www.csharpcorner.com)      -->      `Here you can find articles on various topic, which is needed in daily programming life.`

For Video tutorial, [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) is the best. You can find any topic here with various topics by various .Net Geniuses. You just have to know, what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Github is one of the leading Open Source resources. Take a look https://github.com/

If you are able to pay some money for the courses, I would recommend you to check http://www.pluralsight.com/training.

Answer (score 0):

This website is a faily good resource.

[Language Books/Tutorials for popular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

http://www.codeproject.com/

There are 3 good starting points, but this is a very broad question so really would need to have specifics.