# jquery matching exact string from URL self.location.href

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the following line to match this URL - www.sitename.com/join

```
if(/join/.test(self.location.href)) {joinPopUp();}
```

The catch is it will match /blahjoinblah as well.

How can I change this so it will only match the exact word 'join'.

Note: I think it will have to match '/join' as the '/' is still present (I think).

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression, `\/join(?=\/)` may be what you are looking for. It will check for the `/join` value and then uses [positive look-a-head](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to see whether the character `/` follows.

A quick test within the console:

```
["/xxjoin", "/join/", "/joinme", "joinme"].
          forEach(function (value) { 
                     console.log(value.match(/\/join(?=\/)/));
                  });

// returns the following:

null
["/join", index: 0, input: "/join/"]
null 
null
```

or for readability,

```
["/xxjoin", "/join/", "/joinme", "joinme"].
          filter(function(v) { 
                    return v.match(/\/join(?=\/)/) != null;
                 });

// returns ['/join/']
```

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about Regular Expression read some of these [great resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873/language-books-tutorials-for-popular-languages).

But to answer your question more concretely, if you truly want it to match only `/join` with no query string variables or other input then something like this works in which it checks for the `/` and that it ends with `/join`. Though I suppose that would still match `/foo/join`

```
function testUrl(url) {
    if(/\/join\/?$/.test(url)) {
        console.log(url, "matched /join");
    }
}

testUrl(self.location.href);
testUrl("https://test.com/join");
testUrl("https://test.com/foo/join");
testUrl("http://test.com/blahjoinblah");
```

So you might want to switch up what you are matching - possibly look at `self.location.pathname`